# Parallel minimum euclidean distance on large codes using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp

I have this structure:

```
    struct CacheElem{
        CacheElem(const cv::Mat1f &code, const std::string &result) : code(code), result(result) {}
        cv::Mat1f code;
        std::string result;
    };
```

Then I defined this custom reduction based based on the following `Compare` struct:

```
    struct Compare{
        Compare(double val = std::numeric_limits<double>::max(), size_t index = 0) : val(val), index(index) {}
        double val;
        size_t index;
    };
```

Which is then used in this function:

```
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        Compare localMin;
        #pragma omp for reduction(minimum:min) schedule(dynamic,1)
        for(size_t i=0; i<values.size(); i++){
            D d = distance(queryCode, values[i].code);
            if(d < localMin.val){
                localMin.val = d;
                localMin.index = i;
            }
        }
        #pragma omp critical
        if(localMin.val < min.val)
            min = localMin;
    }
```

`cv::norm` computes the euclidean distance between two row vectors.

Very strangely, this code gave better results than the `reduction` based approach (see previous edits)

When using 100.000 elements in `values`, each one a `cv::Mat1f` of size 1x4096 on a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz, each `QueryCache` call (and it is called 100 times per run) takes around 0.127158 seconds by using 8 thread, while 0.705878 when using 1 thread, which is not terrible, but I'm sure it can be improved. Unfortunately the 6 core machines that I usually use for tests is not available now.

This is how I measure time with `cc::stopTimer()` and `cc::startTimer()`:

```
float timeElapsed(const struct timeval &start){
    struct timeval end;
    float mtime, seconds, useconds;

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    seconds  = end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;

    mtime = seconds + useconds/1000000.0;

    return mtime;

}

struct timeval startTimer(){
    struct timeval start;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    return start;
}
float stopTimer(const struct timeval &start, const std::string &label){
    float time = timeElapsed(start);
    if(!label.empty())
        std::cout<<label<<" time "<<time<<" seconds"<<std::endl;
    return time;
}
```

`totalLookupTime` is simply a class parameter which is used to compute the average time to compute the parallel region between all the different calls of `QueryCache`.

Comment: Are you sure you measured the time correct? And do I understand you correct: You calling the `QueryCache` function multiple times? What is the `totalLookupTime` at the end? And are there no other parallel regions than the one you showed? Regarding the CPI Rate: There ist a gray question mark. It will probably show a tooltip if you click on it or hover over it. CPI is probably the abbreviation for [Cycles (or clocks) per instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycles_per_instruction). Can you make the loop run longer (with a bigger vectors)? Is the value vector even always different?

Comment: @Shadow question updated, btw yes `QueryCache` is called 100 times. `totalLookupTime` is used to compute the average time used in the for loop (I keep track also of the number of times that the function is called). Yes, that's the only parallel region and actually I'm calling only this function to test the scalability of this code.

Comment: @Shadow do you need anything else?

Comment: The naked performance summary with the kernel code is not sufficient to make a good answer. It seems viable and would certainly help to make a [mcve] for this question. Further you should describe specifics about your system: CPU, Memory, sizes of the involved `Mat1f` and `std::vector` (not clear which one 4096 refers to), compiler version and flags, ..

Comment: I updated the question, especially because very strange happened when using `critical` instead of `reduction`! Do you think that the code above is correct to replace the `reduction` version?

Comment: @Zulan you can give a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167501/openmp-simd-euclidean-distance) question (it's still me)

Comment: @Shadow you can give a look at [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/167501/openmp-simd-euclidean-distance) question (I posted it)